# Windows VPN fails after installing - Antivirus causing routing issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn

I have installed VIPRE on my server and Windows VPN fails since then.

It does connect to VPN but I can't access any resources on the server through VPN.

It seems that I'm not getting correct IP address nor Default Gateway under PPP adapter VPN connections on client PC.

Client IP starts with 169. That tells me that it cannot find a DHCP server to get an IP Address from.

Client machine are set to use server's default gateway.

I have turned off VIPRE firewall and everything but still doesn't work.

It must have changed something during the installation.

What settings do I need to change in order to fix this routing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's possible that the Antivirus is causing the underlying problem, but your VPN is failing because you don't have a network connection.

If the client IP starts with 169.254, the network device that you are trying to use to initiate VPN connection isn't getting a real network IP but one of the fallback IPs that are default to Windows.

It's entirely likely that your cable is bad or some other more mundane issue. Maybe rebooting your router if you're using consumer-grade equipment. Or if you're using a real server, check on the status of whichever server is configured to provide you DHCP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. VPN was working fine right before the installation. It seem that I'm not only one having this issue with VIPRE. http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/186540-does-vipre-business-premium-5-natively-block-vpn?page=1#entry-1129580

Comment: While that may be, I'd be hard-pressed to believe that your VPN was working fine while the underlying network interface was assigned a 169.254 link-local interface. You really should look into that aspect and make sure you have a functioning IP since 169.254 are mere placeholders on Windows boxen.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VIPRE, but I'd suggest making sure that you don't have anything blocking outbound DHCP connections from that equipment. Perhaps also running Wireshark on the network to see what packets are being sent from that box would also give you additional information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: uninstalling VIPRE fixed the issue. The tech guy with GFI told me to uninstall Premium version which has firewall function. Obviously there is a problem with that version with VPN.

Comment: Exactly. The software firewall was probably configured to block outbound DHCP requests.